# Is the three dimensions Navier-Stokes equations problem a P problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, computer-science, decision-problems

**Edited.** If we define this problem by a yes/no question, like:

« Does the 3D Navier-Stokes equations problem have a positive solution (which means that there are respecting problem conditions solutions for any respecting problem conditions initial velocity)? »…

…is this problem in P?

[The P vs NP problem where is findable a formal definition of P](https://www.claymath.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/pvsnp.pdf)

[The 3D Navier-Stokes problem](https://www.claymath.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/navierstokes.pdf)

->It seems not because we would have to test an infinite number of different initial velocities (respecting problem conditions) simultaneously in one algorithm?

But couldn’t it be simplified/reduced? Like can’t a Turing machine nevertheless do the job « ignoring » the ignorance of the initial velocity?

This subject mixes computer science and pure mathematics.

I’ve been looking at this subject: [How to prove that problem is not in P?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/25967/how-to-prove-that-problem-is-not-in-p)

But, being really noob in computer science, I don’t know how to begin to prove that the problem is not or is in P yet.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In order to classify a problem's complexity you have to specify exactly what the input is. An example of a reasonable problem is "does the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ have a real solution?" where the input are there numbers $(a,b,c)$ (let's say integers, so that we can easily represent them). So what is the input of your problem?

Comment: Maybe: Does the set of the 3D Navier-Stokes equations have respecting problem conditions solutions (pressure and velocity) for any initial velocity respecting problem conditions? So the input would be the initial velocity? Someone talked to me about the FP set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FP_(complexity), but the output of an FP problem is a function, not a yes/no answer...

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4804217/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/162855/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).